# how to change jQuery autocomplete plugin default querystring key? (term to that i want)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

jQuery autocomplete plugin sent request like this

```
mysite.com/suggestion?term=Sadegh
```

is there any way to change term querystring key to another? i can't find option that provide this for me ;)

Comment: i'm sorry jQuery UI Autocomplete

Comment: Sorry for my answer, i misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you're using [jQuery **UI** AutoComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#options)

You need to provide a callback as the source, like this:

```
$(...).autocomplete({
    source: function(term, callback) {
        $.getJSON("url", { foo: term }, callback);
    }
});
```

Comment: and second quetion: how i can apply effect like fade to list of suggestions?

Comment: Handle the `open` and `close` events.

Answer (score 59):

The above is not correct for the current release (1.8.6). Not sure if it ever was...

```
$(...).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON("url", { foo: request.term }, response);
  }
});
```

foo: being the new param key name..

Comment: Correct.. the accepted solution above gives a malformed url. This one works fine!

Comment: In an ASP.NET MVC application where the search URL is: `server/suggest/{keyword}` I used the function `$.getJSON("/suggest/" + request.term, {}, response);` and it worked

Comment: THIS SHOULD BE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER and yeah sorry for capslock ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I dug up the code that the plugin uses. Adapting it to change the term would be something like this:

```
$('#form').autocomplete({
    source: (function() {
        var xhr;
        return function(request, response) {
            if (xhr) {
                xhr.abort();
            }
            xhr = $.ajax({
                url: 'mysite.com/suggestion',
                data: {
                    foo: request.term
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    response([]);
                }
            });
        }
    })()
});
```

I would say this has 2 advantages:

1. Abort pending requests
2. Call the response with an empty set in case of error, which seems more polite to me