# How to modify autocomplete term prior to sending AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When using JQuery UI Autocomplete, how can I modify the term user entered in the input field, prior to sending the AJAX request?

Eg. user entered `foo` and the backend gets `foo :today`?

I've tried to play with `search()` method but with no luck.

Alternatively, how can I add more query parameters to the `src` upon sending AJAX, once the `src` is already set.
eg. src = `src` + '?when=today'`

I'm trying to provide results based on the values of two fields (search term with param selected from other dropdown)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133510/how-to-change-jquery-autocomplete-plugin-default-querystring-key-term-to-that

Comment: Looks like the callback will do fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

it has a callback, which is invoked before the ajax request:

```
onSearchStart: function (query) {}
```

You can modify the query string/object in place.